# How to extract metadata from NCBI's short read archive (SRA) for a few runs?

Tags: phylogenetics, sratoolkit

I wish to extract metadata from a list of runs on NCBI's short read archive. For instance, I'd like to extract the library name ("HS0798") from the following run info:

https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?view=run_browser&run=SRR390728

I have to extract metadata for a few hundred run numbers. Is there a existing command-line tool (sratoolkit, python, perl, bash, etc) that will extract the *metadata* about the run?

I could grep it out of a webpage dump, but I notice there are XML schemas provided on the site, which to me indicates that there's some sort of XML API available somewhere.

Comment: using xslt, see an old answer I wrote for biostar: https://www.biostars.org/p/69974/#69995

Answer (score 10):

[Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/) is perfect for this sort of thing. You can do something like this:

```
$ esearch -db sra -query 'SRR390728' \
  | efetch -format runinfo \
  | cut -f1,12 -d,
Run,LibraryName
SRR292241,HS0798
SRR390728,HS0798
```

The `runinfo` table format has 47 fields including experiment accession, project accessions, bioproject and biosample identifiers and such. You may want to explore that a little bit more if you are interested in downloading metadata in addition to the LibraryName.

Also, if you prefer to parse XML output, you can append `-mode xml` to the `efetch` command to retrieve the runinfo table in XML format. `xtract` tool that comes with the Entrez Direct package can then be used to convert that into a table.

Comment: Definitely better than my screen grab. I installed the conda package for sratools, which doesn't have that `esearch` binary with it. I'll have to look what package comes with that.

Comment: Follow the installation instructions here: [Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/). There is a package in Ubuntu repositories but it is quite behind from the latest version.

Comment: But it seems that the runinfo is not the same as the RunTable found at this page: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/study/?. For example, go to the link and search for `PRJNA301892`. Under the "select" section (blue flag), there is a `Metadata` button. Is there a way to get that done?

Comment: The `-q` option is not valid with the version I just installed. `-query` should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer to use `-query` now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very crude script version, which should work without downloading fancy software tools. It will only work as long as the website stays in its current layout.

It extracts the particular `<td>` from the webpage, based on a nearby table link ID. and prints it out.

Note: This is brittle. It will only work for library names that fit in a single-line of the HTML, and will ignore some webserver errors. The content is also not html-decoded (so its output might show things like `&amp;` if the field contained html-special characters).

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -o pipefail

# pass the run as a single argument to the script
run="$1"

# extract library name field. second cell in visual order.
curl -o - "https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?view=run_browser&run=$run" 2>/dev/null | \
   grep 'a id="exp-accession"' -A 7 | \
   tail -n +3 | head -n 1 | \
   sed -e 's@^<td>@@' -e 's@</td>$@@'
```

Answer (score 1):

Its got to be the [SRA Toolkit](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?view=software)
The way I would do it (a traditional Perl digger) doesn't work on the Tracer NCBI site, at least not readily and dumping the XML is likewise unlikely to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I've been told by the support team that there's a way to pull it out in csv form by GETting the following URL, replacing `<SRRNUMBER>`, with, e.g. `SRR000001`:

```
https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?save=efetch&db=sra&rettype=runinfo&term=<SRRNUMBER>
```

So this would be:

```
# download the file attachment
wget -nv -O foo.csv  "https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?save=efetch&db=sra&rettype=runinfo&term=SRR000001"

# or just get the output on stdout
curl -v "https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?save=efetch&db=sra&rettype=runinfo&term=SRR000001"
```

As an example, the output looks like this for SRR000001. It namely contains additional info on other runs from the same SRX:

```
Run,ReleaseDate,LoadDate,spots,bases,spots_with_mates,avgLength,size_MB,AssemblyName,download_path,Experiment,LibraryName,LibraryStrategy,LibrarySelection,LibrarySource,LibraryLayout,InsertSize,InsertDev,Platform,Model,SRAStudy,BioProject,Study_Pubmed_id,ProjectID,Sample,BioSample,SampleType,TaxID,ScientificName,SampleName,g1k_pop_code,source,g1k_analysis_group,Subject_ID,Sex,Disease,Tumor,Affection_Status,Analyte_Type,Histological_Type,Body_Site,CenterName,Submission,dbgap_study_accession,Consent,RunHash,ReadHash
SRR000001,2008-04-04 14:36:13,2015-04-07 21:54:15,470985,129515135,236041,274,298,,https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra27/SRR/000000/SRR000001,SRX000007,SID2748,WGS,RANDOM,GENOMIC,PAIRED,3000,0,LS454,454 GS FLX,SRP000001,PRJNA33627,1,33627,SRS000100,SAMN00001583,simple,9606,Homo sapiens,NA18505,,,,,female,,no,,,,,454MSC,SRA000197,,public,25D46C95842BCD2F235DDD48070341C4,5FC1B56C9A5332BD21A6FCC6713C3159
SRR000013,2008-04-04 15:15:44,2012-01-19 15:14:06,478304,131410350,316908,274,307,,https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra4/SRR/000000/SRR000013,SRX000007,SID2748,WGS,RANDOM,GENOMIC,PAIRED,3000,0,LS454,454 GS FLX,SRP000001,PRJNA33627,1,33627,SRS000100,SAMN00001583,simple,9606,Homo sapiens,NA18505,,,,,female,,no,,,,,454MSC,SRA000197,,public,A576F73351E329617F91C92845ADE3BE,0EFE27254FB8790C80E4A8A3A3CCBF1D
SRR000019,2008-04-04 15:20:15,2012-01-19 15:14:06,537808,147928455,358612,275,347,,https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra4/SRR/000000/SRR000019,SRX000007,SID2748,WGS,RANDOM,GENOMIC,PAIRED,3000,0,LS454,454 GS FLX,SRP000001,PRJNA33627,1,33627,SRS000100,SAMN00001583,simple,9606,Homo sapiens,NA18505,,,,,female,,no,,,,,454MSC,SRA000197,,public,5E42E66B2972A28C3C1B714499B3CE1E,A44F729DF562E11BDA4F950F171085B3
SRR000033,2008-04-04 15:26:19,2012-01-19 15:14:16,476737,131230950,316780,275,307,,https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra4/SRR/000000/SRR000033,SRX000007,SID2748,WGS,RANDOM,GENOMIC,PAIRED,3000,0,LS454,454 GS FLX,SRP000001,PRJNA33627,1,33627,SRS000100,SAMN00001583,simple,9606,Homo sapiens,NA18505,,,,,female,,no,,,,,454MSC,SRA000197,,public,8D775F0FB1E78F2818166B4E6C7BC320,6C794108B0172AE98323C9A809BE892E
SRR000047,2008-04-04 15:34:57,2012-01-19 15:14:25,322279,88301883,214744,273,208,,https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra4/SRR/000000/SRR000047,SRX000007,SID2748,WGS,RANDOM,GENOMIC,PAIRED,3000,0,LS454,454 GS FLX,SRP000001,PRJNA33627,1,33627,SRS000100,SAMN00001583,simple,9606,Homo sapiens,NA18505,,,,,female,,no,,,,,454MSC,SRA000197,,public,B4D7BC3DAD22AE58EADC18B2F05B2732,154C9532706F955A63CF685C4D71D9E6
SRR000049,2008-04-04 15:35:58,2012-01-19 15:14:34,506408,139029601,328595,274,336,,https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra4/SRR/000000/SRR000049,SRX000007,SID2748,WGS,RANDOM,GENOMIC,PAIRED,3000,0,LS454,454 GS FLX,SRP000001,PRJNA33627,1,33627,SRS000100,SAMN00001583,simple,9606,Homo sapiens,NA18505,,,,,female,,no,,,,,454MSC,SRA000197,,public,60D02918CD7686DA084607BFD9D8E6A5,E9A732F2A8F36B8EB1CD38CA41BA8FB5
SRR000061,2008-04-04 15:41:48,2012-01-19 15:14:37,532884,146330433,351541,274,348,,https://sra-download.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/traces/sra4/SRR/000000/SRR000061,SRX000007,SID2748,WGS,RANDOM,GENOMIC,PAIRED,3000,0,LS454,454 GS FLX,SRP000001,PRJNA33627,1,33627,SRS000100,SAMN00001583,simple,9606,Homo sapiens,NA18505,,,,,female,,no,,,,,454MSC,SRA000197,,public,8F6E1CA597BCAA19A852036775FA1FAB,2C035CCBD62808A01CEF6EB13BAEB40F
```

Providing an invalid SRR number will generate an empty HTTP 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

Not a command-line tool but also useful is redesigned [SRA Run Selector](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/study/?). Insert comma separated accessions and you can filter/download based on metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can get metadata for an entire project using [pysradb](https://github.com/saketkc/pysradb):

```
> pysradb metadata SRP063732 --detailed

study_accession experiment_accession experiment_title                                                       experiment_desc                                                        organism_taxid  organism_name   library_strategy library_source library_selection sample_accession sample_title instrument           total_spots total_size   run_accession run_total_spots run_total_bases run_alias             sra_url                                                                                 experiment_alias isolate                 dev_stage sex   tissue             treatment     BioSampleModel           
 SRP063732       SRX1249861           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26168_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26168_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071080                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  89051187    11830170462  SRR2420581    89051187        17988339774     26168_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420581/SRR2420581.1                   26168_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249860           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26148_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26148_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071081                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  87335402    11763248173  SRR2420580    87335402        17641751204     26148_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420580/SRR2420580.1                   26148_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249859           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25822_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25822_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071082                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  83544130    9481342835   SRR2420579    83544130        13784781450     25822_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420579/SRR2420579.1                   25822_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249858           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25154_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25154_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071083                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  115476876   13003165573  SRR2420578    115476876       19053684540     25154_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420578/SRR2420578.1                   25154_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249857           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23784_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23784_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071084                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  101539017   13697691917  SRR2420577    101539017       20510881434     23784_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420577/SRR2420577.1                   23784_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249856           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23779_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23779_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071085                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  98394582    13326784419  SRR2420576    98394582        19875705564     23779_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420576/SRR2420576.1                   23779_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249855           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23773_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23773_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071086                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  84442355    11218164664  SRR2420575    84442355        17057355710     23773_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420575/SRR2420575.1                   23773_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249854           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23764_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23764_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071087                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  87197006    11291883405  SRR2420574    87197006        17613795212     23764_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420574/SRR2420574.1                   23764_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249853           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23762_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 23762_HeavyDrinker: Nucleus accumbens  9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071088                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  89455608    11917710767  SRR2420573    89455608        18070032816     23762_NaC_HD_files    https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420573/SRR2420573.1                   23762_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  HeavyEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249852           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25811_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25811_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071089                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  88216999    10285962574  SRR2420572    88216999        14555804835     25811_NaC_LMD _files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420572/SRR2420572.1                   25811_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  LightEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249851           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25790_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25790_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071090                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  94731241    10748979142  SRR2420571    94731241        15630654765     25790_NaC_LMD _files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420571/SRR2420571.1                   25790_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  LightEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249850           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25742_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25742_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071091                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  113512952   17943763654  SRR2420570    113512952       22929616304     25742_NaC_LMD _files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420570/SRR2420570.1                   25742_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  LightEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249849           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25240_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25240_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071092                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  81002663    9232986327   SRR2420569    81002663        13365439395     25240_NaC_LMD _files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420569/SRR2420569.1                   25240_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  LightEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249848           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25184_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25184_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071093                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  110228135   12594727479  SRR2420568    110228135       18187642275     25184_NaC_LMD _files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420568/SRR2420568.1                   25184_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  LightEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249847           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25157_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25157_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071094                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  97249804    11026452312  SRR2420567    97249804        16046217660     25157_NaC_LMD _files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420567/SRR2420567.1                   25157_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  LightEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249846           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 21119_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 21119_LowDrinker: Nucleus accumbens    9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071095                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  68899204    9241244635   SRR2420566    68899204        13917639208     21119_NaC_LMD _files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420566/SRR2420566.1                   21119_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  LightEthanol  Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249845           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26104_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26104_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071096                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  84859783    9604170375   SRR2420565    84859783        14001864195     26104_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420565/SRR2420565.1                   26104_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249844           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26082_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 26082_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071097                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  73346886    8248399265   SRR2420564    73346886        12102236190     26082_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420564/SRR2420564.1                   26082_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249843           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25207_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25207_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071098                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  77306973    12235827725  SRR2420563    77306973        15616008546     25207_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420563/SRR2420563.1                   25207_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249842           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25407_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 25407_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071099                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  83985968    13355795218  SRR2420562    83985968        16965165536     25407_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420562/SRR2420562.1                   25407_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249841           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 24818_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 24818_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071100                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  72782928    8484613123   SRR2420561    72782928        12009183120     24818_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420561/SRR2420561.1                   24818_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249840           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 24698_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 24698_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071101                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  79414016    12627204820  SRR2420560    79414016        16041631232     24698_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420560/SRR2420560.1                   24698_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249839           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 24340_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 24340_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071102                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  84772576    13436053136  SRR2420559    84772576        17124060352     24340_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420559/SRR2420559.1                   24340_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
 SRP063732       SRX1249838           Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 22770_Control: Nucleus accumbens       Bisulfite-seq of rhesus macaque 22770_Control: Nucleus accumbens       9544            Macaca mulatta  Bisulfite-Seq    GENOMIC        other             SRS1071103                    Illumina HiSeq 2000  83310630    13224887149  SRR2420558    83310630        16828747260     22770_NaC_Ctrl_files  https://sra-download.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-3/SRR2420558/SRR2420558.1                   22770_NucleusAccumbens  Adult     male  Nucleus accumbens  Control       Model organism or animal
```